# Auto resize columns in WPF TreeListView

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, resize, treelistview

I am trying to auto resize the columns of WPF TreeListView (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_treelistview_control.aspx) using this code:

```
    public void AutoResizeColumns()
    {
        GridView gv = this.View as GridView;

        if (gv != null)
        {
            foreach (GridViewColumn gvc in gv.Columns)
            {

                if (double.IsNaN(gvc.Width))
                    gvc.Width = gvc.ActualWidth;

                gvc.Width = double.NaN;
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I resize it, the column width is not accounting for the margin of the row and the words are cut off by like 10px and then if I double click the column, it will resize without cutting off the words.

I have also tried this with no luck:

```
    public void AutoResizeColumns()
    {
        GridView gv = this.View as GridView;

        if (gv != null)
        {
            foreach (GridViewColumn gvc in gv.Columns)
            {

                gvc.Width = gvc.ActualWidth + 10;
            }
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying to figure this out, I finally got it. The column Width is being set to ActualWidth which is less then its supposed to be, so if I set the column Width to double.MaxValue then when its set to double.NaN it will resize to the "real" actual width.

Here's the code:

```
public void AutoResizeColumns()
{
    GridView gv = this.View as GridView;

    if (gv != null)
    {
        foreach (GridViewColumn gvc in gv.Columns)
        {
            // Set width to highest possible value
            gvc.Width = double.MaxValue;

            // Set to NaN to get the "real" actual width
            gvc.Width = double.NaN;
        }
    }
}
```